# Gradle: Plugin with id 'android-library' not found

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to automate my projects with Gradle.

I have several apps and one library project.
After having read carefully the [official doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), this is a simplified view of my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://saturday06.github.io/gradle-android-scala-plugin/repository/snapshot"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        // 0.8.3 con Gradle 1.10
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

project(':MyApp') {
    ext.apl = true
}

project(':MyLibrary') {
    ext.apl = false
}

subprojects {
    if (project.apl) {
        apply plugin: 'android'
        dependencies {
            compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
        }
    }
    if (project.scala) {
        apply plugin: 'android-scala'
        scala {
            target "jvm-1.7"
            addparams '-feature'
        }
    } else {
        apply plugin: 'android-library'
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 17
        buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

        signingConfigs { ... }
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 8
            targetSdkVersion 17
        }

        sourceSets {
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            debug {
                runProguard false
                proguardFile file('proguard-rules.txt')
                signingConfig signingConfigs.depurar
            }

            release {
                runProguard true
                proguardFile file('proguard-rules.txt')
                signingConfig signingConfigs.entregar
            }
        }
    }
}

project(':MyLibrary') {
    dependencies {
        compile "com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-2"
        compile "com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-2"
        compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6"

    }
}

project(':MyApp') {
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
        compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1.1') {
            transitive = false
        }
        compile project(':Bibl')
    }
}
```

My settings.gradle is:

```
include 'MyLibrary', 'MyApp'
```

There is only one build.gradle.

The problem is that Gradle complains that

```
Plugin with id 'android-library' not found
```

whenever I try to use this plugin.
With apply plugin: 'android' there is no problem.

The documentation states clearly that for libraries 'android-library' must be used.
I'm using Gradle 1.10.

Is the doc outdated for newest versions of gradle-android-plugin like 1.2.1?  Because the official doc is for version 0.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the doc outdated for newest versions of gradle-android-plugin like 1.2.1?

Quoting [the documentation for `gradle-android-plugin`](https://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin):

> We are very sorry to announce that development of this plugin has been discontinued. Google has created their own Android development toolchain based on Gradle, which supercedes this plugin.
>
> Please see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide for further information.

I usually associate `android-library` with the official Gradle for Android plugin; I have no idea if the deprecated `gradle-android-plugin` supports it.

Comment: Thanks.  I got confused, the good one is: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.4' instead of 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.1'.